# resolve an non-homogeneous differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the given non-homogeneous system:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=3x + 3 y - 2 z + e^t$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = x+y+ 2 z$$
$$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=x+3y+e^t$$

Can you help me understand a simple method to resolve the system?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: Can you write $X'(t) = AX(t) + F(t)$, solve for the eigenvalues of $A$ and then for $F(t)$? Also, were you given any initial conditions?

Comment: We haven't initial conditions. I know this method to compute the solution of homogeneous problem associate. But i don't understand the method to find the particular solution to write the formula of solution of the non-homogeneous problem.

Comment: @Amzoti does your method of solving this question (without initial conditions) work for any $F[t]$ or only for $F[t]$ in the form: $e^{t\alpha} \vec{w}$? because I only see the functions depending on t in this form. (I am using the notation you used in your answer).

Comment: It works for "any" $F(t)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are given the nonhomogeneous system:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=3x + 3 y - 2 z + e^t$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = x+y+ 2 z$$

$$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=x+3y+e^t$$

We can write this as $X'(t) = A x(t) + F[t]$, where:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3& 3 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, ~~ F[t] = \begin{bmatrix} e^t \\ 0 \\ e^t \end{bmatrix}$$

We have the homogeneous solution (you said you know how to find this):

$$X_h(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x_h(t) \\ y_h(t) \\ z_h(t) \end{bmatrix} = c_1e^{4t} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 e^{-2t} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + c_3e^{2t} \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now we need to find the particular solution using the Fundamental Matrix approach, by solving:

$$X(t) = e^{At}X_0 + \int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-s)}F(s)~ds$$

So, we we use a linear combination from the components of the homogeneous solution to write:

- Write $\phi(t) = [x_1(t)~ | ~x_2(t)~ | ~x_3(t)] = \begin{bmatrix} e^{4t} & e^{-2t} & -e^{2t} \\ e^{4t} & -e^{-2t} & e^{2t} \\ e^{4t} & e^{-2t} & e^{2t} \end{bmatrix}$
- Find $\phi^{-1}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-4t}/2 & e^{-4t}/2 & 0 \\ 0 & -e^{2t}/2 & e^{2t}/2 \\ -e^{-2t}/2 & 0 & e^{-2t}/2 \end{bmatrix}$
- Find $\phi^{-1}(t) \cdot F(t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-3t}/2 \\ e^{3t}/2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$
- Now we integrate the previous result and this gives us: $w = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{6}e^{-3t} \\ \dfrac{1}{6}e^{3t} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$
- Next, we find $X_p(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x_p(t) \\ y_p(t) \\ z_p(t) \end{bmatrix} = \phi(t) \cdot w = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -e^{t}/3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

All that is left is to write the final solution as:

$$X(t) = X_h(t) + X_p(t)$$

**Update**

This is adding an example of using the VoP method for a $2x2$ matrix, so you can see the process. You can make up an initial condition for your $3x3$ and emulate this process as you can easily check the result by substituting it back into the system of ODEs.

$x' =  Ax(t) + f(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 6/7 & -15/14 \\ -5/7 & 37/14 \end{bmatrix}~x(t) + \begin{bmatrix} e^{2t} \\ e^{-t} \end{bmatrix}, x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$

$e^{At} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{6}{7}e^{t/2} + \dfrac{1}{7}e^{3t} & \dfrac{3}{7}e^{t/2}- \dfrac{3}{7}e^{3t} \\ \dfrac{2}{7}e^{t/2}- \dfrac{2}{7}e^{3t}  & \dfrac{1}{7}e^{t/2} + \dfrac{6}{7}e^{3t}  \end{bmatrix}$

$e^{At}x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 3e^{t/2} + e^{3t} \\ e^{t/2}-2e^{3t} \end{bmatrix}$

$e^{A(t-s)} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{6}{7}e^{(t-s)/2} + \dfrac{1}{7}e^{3(t-s)} & \dfrac{3}{7}e^{(t-s)/2}- \dfrac{3}{7}e^{3(t-s)} \\ \dfrac{2}{7}e^{(t-s)/2}- \dfrac{2}{7}e^{3(t-s)}  & \dfrac{1}{7}e^{(t-s)/2} + \dfrac{6}{7}e^{3(t-s)}  \end{bmatrix}$

$e^{A(t-s)} \cdot f(s) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{6}{7}e^{(t-s)/2} + \dfrac{1}{7}e^{3(t-s)} & \dfrac{3}{7}e^{(t-s)/2}- \dfrac{3}{7}e^{3(t-s)} \\ \dfrac{2}{7}e^{(t-s)/2}- \dfrac{2}{7}e^{3(t-s)}  & \dfrac{1}{7}e^{(t-s)/2} + \dfrac{6}{7}e^{3(t-s)}  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} e^{2s} \\ e^{-s} \end{bmatrix}$

$\displaystyle \int_0^t e^{A(t-s)} \cdot f(s)~ds = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{3}{7}e^{2t} -\dfrac{5}{28}e^{-t} -\dfrac{2}{7}e^{t/2} + \dfrac{1}{28}e^{3t} \\  \dfrac{10}{21}e^{2t} -\dfrac{13}{42}e^{-t} -\dfrac{2}{21}e^{t/2} - \dfrac{1}{14}e^{3t} \end{bmatrix}$

$\displaystyle x(t) = e^{At}x(0) + \int_0^t e^{A(t-s)} \cdot f(s)~ds = \begin{bmatrix} 3e^{t/2} + e^{3t} \\ e^{t/2}-2e^{3t} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{3}{7}e^{2t} -\dfrac{5}{28}e^{-t} -\dfrac{2}{7}e^{t/2} + \dfrac{1}{28}e^{3t} \\  \dfrac{10}{21}e^{2t} -\dfrac{13}{42}e^{-t} -\dfrac{2}{21}e^{t/2} - \dfrac{1}{14}e^{3t} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{3}{7}e^{2t} -\dfrac{5}{28}e^{-t} +\dfrac{19}{7}e^{t/2} + \dfrac{29}{28}e^{3t} \\  \dfrac{10}{21}e^{2t} -\dfrac{13}{42}e^{-t} +\dfrac{19}{21}e^{t/2} - \dfrac{29}{14}e^{3t} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: We don't understand one point: how you use the formula $$X(t)=e^{At} X_0 + \int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-s)} F(s) ds$$? you haven't compute $e^{Ax}$

Comment: I don't actually use $e^{A t}$, I am showing that this approach comes from Variation of Parameters (VoP). I assumed you would understand that given that you are learning to work with these sorts of systems. Search for VoP and Fundamental Matrix if you are not familiar with how those two work for the solution. The way I find $X_p$ is using the FM approach, but it is all based on VoP for the theory, mixed in with the FM for a solution. Regards

Comment: i think that there is an error on latex in yor message. So please can you redxplain me please?

Comment: See, , problem 9 for example as another example, but search for the above for the theory. http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~asdugas/5A_W09/5AfinrevSol.pdf, Regards

Comment: @jijii: Also note, this would be a lot with initial conditions as then we could easily use that VoP formula, but none were given here, so we have resort to these sorts of tricks. Regards

Comment: Si, we have two cases. case 1: if we have the initial data $X(t_0)=X_0$ then, we use the formula $$X(t)=e^{At}X_0+\int_{t0}^t e^{A(t-s)}F(s)ds$$, case 2: if we don't have the initial data, we must to compute the solution of homogeneous problem and find an particular solution. To find an particular solution:1-we compute $\Phi(t)$ and $Phi^{-1}(t)$,2- find $\Phi^{-1}(t).F(t)=V,$ 3-Integrate $V$ : $\int V = w,$ and finally $$X_p(t)=\Phi(t).w$$ it's okay?

Comment: Yes, very good! One point, if given an initial condition vector, it will be given as $X(0) = C$ and in this case $t_0 = 0$ for the integral. However, the IC may be given as $X(\pi)$, in which case $t_0 = \pi$. I suggest you take a problem with IC and use and don't use the IC and make sure you understand the difference! Regards

Comment: please, can you show me the detail of the method when we have the initial data $X(t_0)=C$ please.

Comment: @jijii: I will add it as an example, but have to do it after getting home from work, so several hours from now. Regards

Comment: I am waiting, and thank you so much.

Comment: @jijii: I added a detailed example for you to work out of a $2x2$, the $3x3$ is too much typing. You can use any initial condition with your $3x3$ and emulate the process. Regards

Comment: Thank you so much! I have an other question please. This two methods are applied when all eigenvalues of $A$ are distincts. But how we can find the solution of an non homogeneous system $X'(t)=A X(t) + F(t)$ when $A$ admits an unique multiple eigenvalue, or her eignevalues with different multiplicities?

Comment: That is no different than the methods used with constant coefficient matrices. Make up a $2x2$ with both eigenvalues the same and work it out. VoP does not change any of those rules.

Comment: But if the matrix $A$ admits for exemple one eigenvalue with multiplicity 2. How we can write the fundamental matrix??