# How would I solve this system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a general solution of

$$
x' =  \begin{pmatrix}
  11 & -25 \\
  4 & -9 
 \end{pmatrix} x + \begin{pmatrix}
  e^{-t} \\
  0 
 \end{pmatrix} $$

I found the general solution of the homogeneous system to be 
$$ c_1e^t \begin{pmatrix}
  5 \\
  2 
 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 \left[te^t\begin{pmatrix}
  5 \\
  2
 \end{pmatrix} +e^t \begin{pmatrix}
  3 \\
  1 
 \end{pmatrix} \right] 
$$

I am not sure how to go about solving the nonhomogeneous form. The only method I know is variation of parameters but that seems very impractical in this situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could accept more answers. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Do you know how to find a matrix exponential? Do you know about *fundamental* and *special matrices*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the general solution you found.

See my post here for details of this process, [resolve an non-homogeneous differential system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492040/resolve-an-non-homogeneous-differential-system).

We have:

$$\phi(t) = e^t \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 5 t+3 \\
 2 & 2 t+1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\phi^{-1}(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -e^{-t} (2 t+1) & e^{-t} (5 t+3) \\
 2 e^{-t} & -5 e^{-t} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\phi^{-1}(t).f(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -e^{-t} (2 t+1) & e^{-t} (5 t+3) \\
 2 e^{-t} & -5 e^{-t} \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 e^{-t} \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -e^{-2 t} (2 t+1) \\
 2 e^{-2 t} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Integrating this previous result yields:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -e^{-2 t} (-t-1) \\
 -e^{-2 t} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

We now multiply the previous result with $\phi(t)$, yielding a particular solution of:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 e^{-t} \\
 e^{-t} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Finally, our solution is:

$$x(t) = x_h(t) + x_p(t) =  c_1e^t \begin{pmatrix}
  5 \\
  2 
 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 \left[te^t\begin{pmatrix}
  5 \\
  2
 \end{pmatrix} +e^t \begin{pmatrix}
  3 \\
  1 
 \end{pmatrix} \right] 
 + \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 e^{-t} \\
 e^{-t} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I have a question for your $\phi^{-1}$. Why does $e^t$ become $e^{-t}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the matrix inverse formula for a $2x2$? Recall, that $e^t$ term is part of **each** matrix entry. In other words, you have $\phi(t) =  \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5e^t & e^t(5 t+3) \\
 2e^t & e^t(2 t+1) \\
\end{array}
\right)$. Clear?

Comment: Ah, Ok got it. I wasn't including it in the inversion since I thought it was constant outside the matrix.